# C++/CLI type-cast operator

Tags: casting, c++-cli, operator-overloading

I have two classes: `testClass` and `castClass`:

```
class testClass
{
public:
    int field1;
    int field2;

    testClass(int f1, int f2) : field1(f1), field2(f2) {}
};

ref class castClass
{
    int i;
    int j;
public:
    castClass(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}

    explicit static operator testClass (castClass% c)
    {
        return testClass(c.i, c.j);
    }
};
```

When I try:

```
castClass cc(1, 2);
testClass i = (testClass)cc;
```

it compiles fine.

but when I try to cast as:

```
castClass% c = castClass(1, 2);
testClass j = (testClass)c;
```

compiler throws the error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 
'castClass' to 'testClass'
```

Why second case is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's because now c is already reference so it interprets 'c%' as 'c%%' (double reference). If it is I'm not sure how you would de-reference.

Comment: You are trying to cast a pointer to an object, not permitted.  You could invoke the operator directly: `testClass j = castClass::operator testClass(c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `castClass` is a ref class, the normal way to refer to objects of that type is with `^`. Try this, it should work for you.

```
ref class castClass
{
    int i;
    int j;
public:
    castClass(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}

    explicit static operator testClass (castClass^ c)
    {
        return testClass(c->i, c->j);
    }
};

castClass^ cc = gcnew castClass(1, 2);
testClass i = (testClass)cc;

castClass^% c = gcnew castClass(1, 2);
testClass j = (testClass)c;
```